# Show a nonabelian group $G$ of order $pq$, with $p$ and $q$ two different primes, is solvable but not nilpotent. Show that it exists when $q\mid p-1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that a nonabelian group G of order $pq$, with $p$ and $q$ two different prime numbers, is solvable but not nilpotent. Show that such a group exists whenever $q |p-1$. (Hint: Consider upper triangular subgroups of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$).

I understand how to show that $G$ is solvable, but I'm not sure how to show it is not nilpotent or the such a group exists whenever $q|p-1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ were nilpotent, it would be a direct product of its Sylow subgroups, hence  $G$ would be abelian, as the Sylow subgroups are cyclic.

If $q|p-1$, then $\operatorname{Aut}(C_p) \cong C_{p-1}$ has an element of order $q$ (take a generator $x$ and it to the $\frac{p-1}{q}$-th power), where $C_k$ is the cyclic group of order $k$. This element gives rise to a nontrivial homomorphism $\varphi:C_q \to \operatorname{Aut}(C_p)$. Thus a non-abelian group of order $pq$ exists as the semidirect product $ C_p\rtimes_\varphi C_q$.